# How to balance binary tree in PHP without rotating parent?

Tags: php, modified-preorder-tree-t, tree-balancing

I will try to make myself as clear as possible. Based from Adjacency List Model: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database

I need a way to balance this tree

```
     0 
    / \ 
   1   2 
  /   / \ 
 3    4  5 
       \  \
        6  7
```

to something like:

```
        0 
      /   \ 
     1     2 
    / \   / \ 
   3   4 5   6
  /
 7
```

Based from the sample Code:

```
<?php 
function display_children($parent, $level) { 
   $result = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM tree '. 
                          'WHERE parent="'.$parent.'";'); 
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
       echo str_repeat('  ',$level).$row['title']."\n"; 
       display_children($row['title'], $level+1); 
   } 
} 
?>
```

I modified the code so it can output a flat html table like this:

$super_parent = '0000'
left Node entries into flat list:

```
 ____________________________________________________
| No. | Date of Entry       | Account ID  | Placement|
------------------------------------------------------
| 1   | 2010-08-24 11:19:19 | 1111a       |    a     |
| 2   | 2010-08-24 11:19:19 | 22221a_a    |    a     |
| 3   | 2010-08-24 11:19:19 | 33_2aa      |    b     | 
| 4   | 2010-08-24 11:19:19 | 33_2Ra      |    a     | 
| 5   | 2010-08-24 11:19:19 | 22221a_b    |    b     |
| 6   | 2010-08-24 11:19:19 | 33_2ba      |    a     |
| 7   | 2010-08-24 11:19:19 | 33_2bb      |    b     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

But I need a way to reorganize all this into a balanced tree without moving or rotating the parent. Although I can think of creating a duplicate table in the db and do a second  query to display or create another Binaray tree, I thought it may be possible to reorganize a flat tree like this into:

```
        0 
      /   \ 
     1     2 
    / \   / \ 
   3   4 5   6
  /
 7
```

From left to right. 0 represents the parent or super_parent 0000.

The reason I would like to do this is so I can create a virtual tree from the original tree that will be the basis of another algorithm in my project.

Thanks in advance.

Bob

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have decided to answer my own question with this discovery. In General, this can be called, the "Distribution Method" of recursively automating a Balanced Binary Tree from left to right. This algorithm makes sure to take care of 64 pairs per level and the rest would be flushed out : )

```
<?php
function makeBTree($load, $colMult, $levCount){
    $exCol=$colMult;
    if($load<=$colMult){
        $exCol=$load;
    } if($load>0) {echo "Load: $load ";} else {echo "Load: 0 ";}
    echo "Level: $levCount ";
    echo "Columns: ";

    for($i=1;$i<=$exCol; $i++){

    }

    if($i<=64) {
        echo "<font color='violet'>".($exCol)." candidate for pairing if count matches with TEAM B</font> \n";
    } else {
        $limiter = ($i)-64; 
        echo "<font color='orange'>$i</font> - <font color='black'>64</font> = 
        <font color='blue'>$limiter auto-flushout</font> \n";   
    }

    $load -=$colMult; if($load>0) {echo "Load: $load ";} else {echo "Load: 0";}
    echo "<br />\n";

    if($load>=1){
        makeBTree($load,$colMult*2, $levCount+1);
    }
}

makeBTree(1000,1,1);
?>
```

The left frontline node of super parent should be counted as 1. For 8 entries left, just call:

```
makeBTree(8,1,1);
```

Thanks

Oliver Bob Lagumen

Comment: This is a non OOP approach though. The Binary tree has been made. Then this sidelick binary algorithm has been added.

Comment: ok, s-e-n-d it to my yah-oo m-a-i-l "pcc_webmaster" please add the at-y-a-hoo-dot com. I have a new question related to limit of pairs per day before flush out. Please have a look If you are pleased to help, I need to have a clear picture about it. My deadline is on 27 of Feb. 2011.

Comment: sirin, I'd like to ask the copy of this code you explained above for personal study.

My email address is: "pcc_webmaster@yahoo.com". Thanks in advance.

Oliver Bob Lagumen

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete code i used to build a binary tree datastructure and its corresponding operations:

```
<?php
class Node
{
 public $data;
 public $leftChild;
 public $rightChild;

 public function __construct($data)
  {
   $this->data=$data;
   $this->leftChild=null;
   $this->rightChild=null;
  }
 public function disp_data()
  {
   echo $this->data;
  }


}//end class Node
class BinaryTree
{
 public $root;
 //public $s;
 public function __construct()
  {
   $this->root=null;
   //$this->s=file_get_contents('store');

  }
//function to display the tree
  public function display()
  {
   $this->display_tree($this->root);

  }
  public function display_tree($local_root)
  {

   if($local_root==null) 
     return;
    $this->display_tree($local_root->leftChild);
    echo $local_root->data."<br/>";
    $this->display_tree($local_root->rightChild);

  } 
// function to insert a new node
  public function insert($key)
   {
    $newnode=new Node($key);
      if($this->root==null)
        {
         $this->root=$newnode;
         return;
        }
      else
        {
         $parent=$this->root;
         $current=$this->root;
           while(true)
             {
               $parent=$current;
                 //$this->find_order($key,$current->data);
                if($key==($this->find_order($key,$current->data)))
                  {
                      $current=$current->leftChild;
                       if($current==null)
                         {
                          $parent->leftChild=$newnode;
                          return;
                         }//end if2
                  }//end if1 
                else
                  {
                      $current=$current->rightChild;
                       if($current==null)
                         {
                          $parent->rightChild=$newnode;
                          return;  
                         } //end if1                       
                  } //end else
             }//end while loop 
        }//end else

   } //end insert function

//function to search a particular Node
 public function find($key)
  {
    $current=$this->root;
     while($current->data!=$key)
          {
            if($key==$this->find_order($key,$current->data))
              {
                $current=$current->leftChild;
              }
            else
              {
                $current=$current->rightChild;
              }
            if($current==null)
              return(null);

          }
         return($current->data); 
  }// end the function to search
 public function delete1($key)
  {
    $current=$this->root;
    $parent=$this->root;

    $isLeftChild=true;
     while($current->data!=$key)
          {
           $parent=$current;
           if($key==($this->find_order($key,$current->data)))
             {
              $current=$current->leftChild;
              $isLeftChild=true;
             }   
           else
             {
              $current=$current->rightChild;
              $isLeftChild=false;   
             } 
            if($current==null)
              return(null);
          }//end while loop 

      echo "<br/><br/>Node to delete:".$current->data;
     //to delete a leaf node 
     if($current->leftChild==null&&$current->rightChild==null)
       {
           if($current==$this->root)
              $this->root=null;  
          else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=null;
           }  
         else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=null;
           }
         return($current);       
       }//end if1
     //to delete a node having a leftChild 
   else if($current->rightChild==null)
       {
          if($current==$this->root)
           $this->root=$current->leftChild;
          else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=$current->leftChild;
           }
          else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=$current->leftChild;
           }   
          return($current);
       }//end else if1
    //to delete a node having a rightChild
   else if($current->leftChild==null)
       {
         if($current==$this->root)
           $this->root=$current->rightChild;
         else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=$current->rightChild;
           }  
         else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=$current->rightChild; 
           }  
           return($current);
       }  
   //to delete a node having both childs
    else
       {
        $successor=$this->get_successor($current);
        if($current==$this->root)
          {
            $this->root=$successor; 

          }
        else if($isLeftChild==true)
          {
           $parent->leftChild=$successor;
          }
        else
          {
           $parent->rightChild=$successor;
          }     
         $successor->leftChild=$current->leftChild;
        return($current);
       }   


  }//end the function to delete a node
//Function to find the successor node
 public function get_successor($delNode)
  {
   $succParent=$delNode;
   $successor=$delNode;
   $temp=$delNode->rightChild;
    while($temp!=null)
         {
          $succParent=$successor;
          $successor=$temp;
          $temp=$temp->leftChild;
         }
   if($successor!=$delNode->rightChild)
     {
      $succParent->leftChild=$successor->rightChild;
      $successor->rightChild=$delNode->rightChild;
     }
  return($successor);
  }
//function to find the order of two strings
 public function find_order($str1,$str2)
  {
     $str1=strtolower($str1);
     $str2=strtolower($str2);
     $i=0;
     $j=0;

     $p1=$str1[i];
     $p2=$str2[j]; 
  while(true)
   {  
       if(ord($p1)<ord($p2)||($p1==''&&$p2==''))
         {

           return($str1);
         }
      else
         {
           if(ord($p1)==ord($p2))
             {
              $p1=$str1[++$i];
              $p2=$str2[++$j];
              continue;
             }
          return($str2); 
         }
   }//end while

  } //end function find string order

 public function is_empty()
  {
    if($this->root==null)
      return(true);
    else
      return(false);
  }
}//end class BinaryTree
?>
```

Comment: sirin, can you show me a copy of your PHP script source? Because it is not rendered properly here in this page.